# Page showing blank Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

i have a laravel project that's supposed to get a person's referral 3 levels deep. Here is my controller with its query.

```
public function matrix()
{    
    $referrals = DB::table('users')->where('referred_by', Auth::user()->referral_id)->get();

    if (empty($referrals))
    {
        return view('matrix');
    }
    elseif(isset($referrals[0]))
    {
        $referrals2gen = DB::table('users')->where('referred_by', $referrals[0]->referral_id)->get();

        if (!isset($referrals2gen[0])) 
        {
            $referrals3gen = DB::table('users')->where('referred_by', $referrals2gen[0]->referral_id)->get();

            if (!isset($referrals3gen[0]))
            {
                return view('matrix3', ['referrals' => $referrals, 'referrals2gen' => $referrals2gen]);
            }
            elseif(isset($referrals3gen[0]))
            {
                return view('matrix4', ['referrals' => $referrals, 'referrals2gen' => $referrals2gen, 'referrals3gen' => $referrals3gen]);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

if a user has referrals it returns the normal view. If he doesnt it retruns a blank page. Will appreciate any help whatsover.
NOTE: i know its not DRY but am a beginner and i have been having issues with these for a while

Comment: have you add permission to the storage and cache directory?

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: means to run laravel application you need to add the permission

Comment: am running it on a web host. 1and1. Like i said i am just a beginner developer so i would appreciate detailed explanation

Comment: Your if syntax is wrong. you should fix it. `if (!isset($referrals2gen[0])) ` after this you have just start the block and there are no codes and ending block.

Comment: MisaGH I know my syntax is wrong. But dunno how I can fix. I have tried a lot of other ways. Please I'd appreciate your help in details

Comment: If I make variations it sometimes shows me undefined offset 0

Comment: First please update your code to the right syntax

Comment: Oh! Updated it already. Thanks for pointing that Out!

Comment: You have not written any `else` or `elseif` after this `if (!isset($referrals2gen[0])) ` and maybe this condition is not working and then nothing will be viewed

Answer (score 0):

Why are you querying in a controller.. The best way to solve your problem easier is to create a repository and leave the controller clean.
And for the query you better use eloquent is simple

Here is a link

https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/

Comment: Am actually querying in a controller cos am lazy. I prefer to go back and forth between views and controllers. But I'll refine my code later on. Just need help with the correct code syntax

Answer (score 0):

Add `else` after this `if`

```
    if (!isset($referrals2gen[0])) 
    {
        $referrals3gen = DB::table('users')->where('referred_by', $referrals2gen[0]->referral_id)->get();

        if (!isset($referrals3gen[0]))
        {
            return view('matrix3', ['referrals' => $referrals, 'referrals2gen' => $referrals2gen]);
        }
        elseif(isset($referrals3gen[0]))
        {
            return view('matrix4', ['referrals' => $referrals, 'referrals2gen' => $referrals2gen, 'referrals3gen' => $referrals3gen]);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        return view(...);
    }
```